# Why does gradle resolve dependencies at configure time?

Tags: gradle

We have some "heavy weight" artifacts, and we don't necessarily always need them. If we have some tasks with dependencies to them, they will get downloaded, regardless of the task which we invoke.

It would be nice if gradle only downloaded dependencies when it actually needs them.

Example

```groovy
configurations {
  webresources
}
dependencies {
  webresources my:hugeIconCollection:2.0@zip
}
def unpackIcons = tasks.register('unpackIcons', Copy) {
  configurations.webresources.resolveConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {
    from zipTree(it.file)
    into 'resources/path'
  }
}
```

Now simply running `gradle help` will already download the `hugeIconCollection.zip`.
The code uses the "Configuration Avoidance API", but it doesn't help. Still it would be desirable that the resource only be downloaded when the `unpackIcons` task is run (or a task that dependsOn it), and then the file be unzipped into the destination path.

Comment: Gradle doesn't have lazy dependency evaluation AFAIK, so it resolves all dependencies during configuration time. (There are some hacks you can do to make lazy dependencies, of course).

Comment: Artifact dependencies do get resolved lazily (and always have been).

Comment: So what is the way to insure that I'm not breaking lazy downloads? I can only guess that it has to do with accessing dependency metadata (e.g. sources.files) - but I need to access that data in the task body...

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by `sources.files` and "task body". The question is too abstract/vague to give concrete advice. Perhaps you can create a minimal example and base your question on that.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I find it perfectly understandable, it's a natural requirement to treat dependent resources in tasks. I'll see if I can provide a simple enough example.

Answer (score 2):

Gradle downloads dependencies just-in-time on their first use. If your build downloads dependencies at configuration time, then because your build scripts/plugins are using them at configuration time. In most cases this indicates a problem with the build scripts/plugins.

Comment: Ok, so I guess this means that one cannot access dependency metadata without incurring the wrath of preloading.

Comment: `configurations.xxx.(all)Dependencies` will get you the `xxx` (`compile`, `runtime`, etc.) dependencies declared in the build script, without downloading anything. If you need more than that, some resolution and download will obviously have to occur. It's then a matter of choosing the right API (`configuration.incoming`, `configuration.resolvedConfiguration`, etc.) for the task at hand. Besides you should reconsider if you really need dependency metadata at configuration time.

Comment: `configurations.xxx.dependencies` will not allow me to express that I want e.g. the artifact be unzipped once it has been downloaded. Or does it?